# Why am I getting this New York output alone?

Tags: r

Consider the following vector ‘tels’ which contains telephone numbers from “KANSAS”, “TEXAS” and “NEW YORK” regions.

tels <-  c("510-548-2238", "707-231-2440", "650-752-1300", "510-674-3482", "510-853-5695", "510-882-9898", "650-555-6311", "707-885-6351", "650-231-1234", "650-096-0023", "707-691-6763")

```
If the number starts with 510, the phone number is from “KANSAS”, if it is 707, then “NEW YORK” and if it is 650 then the number is from “TEXAS”

Use R concepts and obtain the following dataframe as ouput.

               Expected Output:

                  PhoneNumbers            State

               1     5105482238       KANSAS

               2     7072312440   NEW YORK

               3     6507521300          TEXAS

               4     5106743482       KANSAS

               5     5108535695       KANSAS

               6     5108829898       KANSAS

               7     6505556311         TEXAS

               8     7078856351   NEW YORK

               9     6502311234         TEXAS

               10   6500960023         TEXAS

               11   7076916763   NEW YORK



This is my code :

z<-substr(tels,1,3)
dirt<-data.frame(tels,z)
dirt
for(i in z){
  if(i==510){
    sta<-"ddfdd"
  }if(i==707){
    sta<-"NEW YORK"
  }
  if((i==650)){
    sta<-"TEXAS"
  }

}
das<-data.frame(tels,sta)
das


but I'm getting this output:
          tels      sta
1  510-548-2238 NEW YORK
2  707-231-2440 NEW YORK
3  650-752-1300 NEW YORK
4  510-674-3482 NEW YORK
5  510-853-5695 NEW YORK
6  510-882-9898 NEW YORK
7  650-555-6311 NEW YORK
8  707-885-6351 NEW YORK
9  650-231-1234 NEW YORK
10 650-096-0023 NEW YORK
11 707-691-6763 NEW YORK
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `factor` with the labels being the `state` and labels being the first 3 digits

```
data.frame(tels,
 state = factor(substr(tels,0,3), c('510','650','707'), c('KANSAS','TEXAS','NEW YORK')))
           tels    state
1  510-548-2238   KANSAS
2  707-231-2440 NEW YORK
3  650-752-1300    TEXAS
4  510-674-3482   KANSAS
5  510-853-5695   KANSAS
6  510-882-9898   KANSAS
7  650-555-6311    TEXAS
8  707-885-6351 NEW YORK
9  650-231-1234    TEXAS
10 650-096-0023    TEXAS
11 707-691-6763 NEW YORK
```

Answer (score 1):

We `substr` the 'tels' and then create a named `vector` to match the substr values and replace it with the values in the named vector

```
data.frame(PhoneNumbers = tels, state = setNames(c("KANSAS", "NEW YORK", "TEXAS"),
               c('510', '707', '650'))[substr(tels, 1, 3)])
#   PhoneNumbers    state
#1  510-548-2238   KANSAS
#2  707-231-2440 NEW YORK
#3  650-752-1300    TEXAS
#4  510-674-3482   KANSAS
#5  510-853-5695   KANSAS
#6  510-882-9898   KANSAS
#7  650-555-6311    TEXAS
#8  707-885-6351 NEW YORK
#9  650-231-1234    TEXAS
#10 650-096-0023    TEXAS
#11 707-691-6763 NEW YORK
```

Comment: I want the output as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find *first pattern* using `^510`, `^650`, and `^707`. To easily add new column, I have used `dplyr` package.

```
library(tidyverse) # has dplyr and stringr
# data set -------------------------------
(dirt <- data_frame(PhoneNumbers = c("510-548-2238", "707-231-2440", "650-752-1300", "510-674-3482", "510-853-5695", "510-882-9898", "650-555-6311", "707-885-6351", "650-231-1234", "650-096-0023", "707-691-6763")))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 1
#>    PhoneNumbers
#>    <chr>       
#>  1 510-548-2238
#>  2 707-231-2440
#>  3 650-752-1300
#>  4 510-674-3482
#>  5 510-853-5695
#>  6 510-882-9898
#>  7 650-555-6311
#>  8 707-885-6351
#>  9 650-231-1234
#> 10 650-096-0023
#> 11 707-691-6763
```

You can make function to find each region by finding each pattern: `stringr::str_detect()`

You can do it at once using `sapply()`. If you perform `str_detect` to `c("^510", "^650", "^707")`, you will get a matrix each of which column is the number. Each value is whether the number contains the pattern(`TRUE` or `FALSE`), i.e. 11 x 3.

For each row, you have only one `TRUE` by construction. You can find this index and subset `c("KANSAS", "TEXAS", "NEW YORK")`.

```
find_region <- function(x) {
  sta <- c("^510", "^650", "^707")
  stt <- sapply(sta, function(p) {
    str_detect(x, pattern = p)
  }) %>% # produce matrix 11x3 of TRUE and FALSE, each column = 510, 650, 707, TRUE if x contains the pattern
    apply(1, which) # get the index
  c("KANSAS", "TEXAS", "NEW YORK")[stt]
}
```

Using this function, you can add new column: `dplyr::mutate()`

```
dirt %>% 
  mutate(State = find_region(PhoneNumbers))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    PhoneNumbers State   
#>    <chr>        <chr>   
#>  1 510-548-2238 KANSAS  
#>  2 707-231-2440 NEW YORK
#>  3 650-752-1300 TEXAS   
#>  4 510-674-3482 KANSAS  
#>  5 510-853-5695 KANSAS  
#>  6 510-882-9898 KANSAS  
#>  7 650-555-6311 TEXAS   
#>  8 707-885-6351 NEW YORK
#>  9 650-231-1234 TEXAS   
#> 10 650-096-0023 TEXAS   
#> 11 707-691-6763 NEW YORK
```